# Does VSCode remote-ssh extension in remote development store ANY info client side?

Tags: security, memory, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

This is a security oriented question.  Basically I'm reviewing the appdata for vscode and I see a couple of cache files. I'm trying to figure out if any of the file data is being transferred into client OS since that would be a security violation.  I don't see a firm answer on this anywhere.  Microsoft saying that it's "Sandboxed" isn't good enough for my security concerns, I need to be reasonably certain.

Basically if vscode-remote is ultimately a renderer like an ssh terminal it's okay, however if it does even a small amount of plain text caching on WINDOWS that's a no no since ultimately I'd be bypassing the security of the server.

Just to be clear my *access* is secured over ssh and approved, but my viewing on the client side is what's in question.

It appears to be okay(haven't found any files in violation), but I need something firmer, and of course it needs to be from an official source. (or offer direct proof to substantiate the use case as secure).

Comment: This might be better taken up on their twitter feed: https://twitter.com/code if you need to talk to people who really know the insides

Comment: Guess ill have to make a Twitter account XD. Though ill leave this open for the time being!

Comment: I did tweet at code and a vscode engineer, but no response, so it stays open. Please if someone knows respond. Im dying under my vnc latency :-S

Answer (score 3):

This is not actually my own answer one of the vscode development team(Chuck Lantz) responded to a direct question by email.

> Okay, have an update.  We don’t currently have the equivalent of an “In-Private”
> mode in the browser context where all caching is in RAM.

> You can, however, run VS Code in portable mode and keep the contents in a more
> secure location. This keeps all data relative to the application folder so you
> could put some or all of it in an encrypted virtual hard drive or even on a
> remote file share (e.g. using SSHFS).

> [Portable Mode in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable)

> It defaults to using the system temp location for some content, but you can
> change that to a sub-folder as well. The location of data folders by OS is also listed in the article.

Thanks Chuck!